# Div background not showing in any IE before V9

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer, html

I have a div :

```
<div class="ContainerBG">
    Special Ad
</div>
```

and a css :

```
    .ContainerBG
{
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-image: url('Resources/images/ContainerBG.gif');
}
```

In all browsers and in IE9 the background is showing correctly, but in IE8 or less the background isn't showing at all, however the other properties in 'ContainerBG' are working! and i a can see the background rendered correctly in IE Developer Tool!

I also tried :

```
 background: url('Resources/images/ContainerBG.gif') repeat-x;
```

i also tried to pass the style inline and it didn't work!

If we replaced the div with a span for the same CSS it will work!
A test page is [here](http://www.fedne.com/Default_en.aspx) please note that the left pane is the div i am talking about, and the right pane have the same code but using a span, as you can see the span is working but the div Not!!

Does anybody face same problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle

Comment: Works like a charm in IE8 - maybe there is a problem loading the image? Have you tried a different one?

Comment: Do you have a valid DOCTYPE Declaration in your markup?

Comment: I note that it's a relative URL. Perhaps IE8 is treating that path differently to other browsers? Have you tried using a fully qualified path?

Comment: Thanks all, I've uploaded a test page here:
http://www.fedne.com/Default_en.aspx
please note that the left side is a div i am talking about, and the right have the same code but using a span, as you can see the span is working but the div Not!!

Comment: the problem appears just in IE 8 and before!,
the DOCTYPE is there, the image is ok and the URL is also fine as you can see it's working for the span

Comment: I'm gonna take a wild stab and say that < IE9 doesn't like that [style block you have in the body starting on line 126](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fedne.com%2FDefault_en.aspx&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: @Ala, I looked at your CSS and suspect that IE8 doesn't like how some CSS properties separated. It is possible that you have `\r` only instead of `\r\n`. Can you manually add new lines between CSS properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ala, if I remove `content: ' ';` from `.QAZ-layout-cell QAZ-sidebar1`, I can see the background of the `div`.  IE8 only supports the content property if a !DOCTYPE is specified.

Comment: Thank you so much, You're right!, removing the  `content: ' ';` has solved the problem, Although i lost the background color! but i believe it's easy to solve that.

Comment: I am confused now, Even if the !DOCTYPE is specified. if i removed the content property the background image appears but the background color disappears!,
 and vice versa if i keep the content property the background image disappears but the background color appears! do you have any suggestions, please tell me if i have to ask another question for that issue.Thanks

Comment: @Ala, honestly, your CSS is a mess. I see a lot of z-indexes, absolute and relative positionings and overall too busy for a quite simple layout like this. What I advise you to do is to open IE's Developer Tools (F12 key) and navigate to the element. You can modify styles of the selected element on the fly and it will help you to understand what causes what. Another solution would be to find a CSS for your layout on the internet, e.g. http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm

Comment: Actually It's auto generated and used for many portals in different styles, however you're right, I'll do it manually, no other choice, Thanks for you contribution.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this in your head tag:

```
<!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```